# Drop string that is all zeros - pandas python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe of strings that looks like this:

```
In [58]: d['upin'].head()
Out[58]:
0    'H8409  
1    'H8409
2    .31961
3    .31961
4    000000
Name: upin, dtype: object
```

I want to drop the rows that have only zeros, i.e. the last row in this example. I haven't found a nice regexp way of doing this, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried `^0+$`? If you could provide more details about the example (e.g. datatype where you store those strings) we may provide sth more complex (with python code)

Comment: Maybe you can try `df[~(df['pin'].str.contains('^0+$'))]`.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my question with some more details about the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pd.to_numeric:

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.pin,errors='coerce').ne(0)]
Out[278]: 
     pin
1  F4923
2  '222R
4  00001
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work if I understood your problem correctly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['pin'] = ["00000","F4923","'222R","0","00001"]
ndf = df[~(df['pin'].str.contains('^0+$'))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.contains

```
df = df[df.upin.str.contains('[^0]')]
```

You get

```
    upin
0   'H8409
1   'H8409
2   .31961
3   .31961
```